How should I do the soffit on this 200sq ft addition?
200 sq ft addition, gable roof. Siding is fiber cement. Contractor who bailed already installed the same siding to be used as the fascia. Separately, there is the pop-out below the future soffit - which is for a recessed shelf above the door inside. Those 2 areas seem to get in each other's way and I'm not sure what to do where they "meet".
My question is - how should I install the soffit? I'd prefer if the eaves are sloped parallel to the roof, but having them level is fine too if it's easier/the only reasonable option. I'm most puzzled about where the pop-out and soffit will meet.





You have multiple questions here, which wouldn't be a problem if the answers were simple. They really aren't, as soffit should've been done before both siding and fascia and now things get a bit putzy. Please revise to ask just one specific question, and post others if needed. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

FYI, roof pitches aren't described in degrees. They're described as rise:run, like 4:12. My guess is that your roof is either 4:12 or 5:12, but your angle falls between them.

When you revise, be sure to indicate whether you want your eave soffits level or sloped parallel to the roof.

How's this ventilated?

@Huesmann, I installed 2 mushroom vents on the roof. At the base of the gable, where the pop-out will be getting in the way of the soffit, there is some open space there going into the rafters, as well. You can kinda see in pic 2. Mentioning because if I use vented soffit, that's even more airflow going in the rafters.

@TioS but how would vented soffits even vent?  I only see OSB—no opening.

@Huesmann sorry- there are openings at each gable base where it meets the pop-outs, can kinda see in pics 2-3. Can fit both fists in each.  As you go up the slope for several inches there’s an opening as well of just an inch or 2.  Can see in pic 2. Installed 2-mushroom vents on top. Vaulted MDF ceilings so there’s no attic. I used both fiberglass and bubble aluminum insulation. All this was planned by the contractor who bailed and robbed me so I can’t ask exactly what his plan was.
